# Bulk Insert with a wrong data in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, bulkinsert

I am trying to set up an automated data workflow for my company, inserting data into a database (microsoft sql server) every Monday.

The "Bulk Insert" statement will insert data row by row. However, if it finds wrong data in the middle, it will stop the process and it won't take out the data that were inserted.

Is there any way that we can validate the data first so that it won't start inserting until it validates that the data are clean to be inserted?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a very broad question, and will probably be closed. For starters, you haven't provided any information about the data format, or what "validation" means. FWIW, I'd either write a simple powershell script to do the validation, or use SSIS to read the file, validate it, and then get it to do the Bulk Insert if validation passes.

Comment: I think comments below mentions about 'Transaction' which I believe is what I need for now! Having a validation for each row is also a great idea, I will work on that afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... if it finds wrong data in the middle, it will stop the process and it won't take out the data that were inserted.

Use a transaction, that is exactly what they were made for (*to roll back or commit multiple operations as a part of a transaction*)

> #### [General Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#general-remarks)
>
> The BULK INSERT statement can be executed within a user-defined transaction to import data into a table or view. Optionally, to use multiple matches for bulk importing data, a transaction can specify the BATCHSIZE clause in the BULK INSERT statement. If a multiple-batch transaction is rolled back, every batch that the transaction has sent to SQL Server is rolled back.

Example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION TrnBlkInsert
BEGIN TRY
   -- your bulk insert here
   BULK INSERT .....

   COMMIT TRANSACTION TrnBlkInsert
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TrnBlkInsert;
   THROW;
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! this is all I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

Validate every row before insert is a way.
But still something wrong may happen when you do insert.
So, you may consider Transaction. the whole insert in one Transaction.
Any row insert fail. database will rollback all.
with transaction. you don't need validate before.

Comment: Transaction it is ! Thank you very much! I will look more information about "Transaction"